# How can I use Julia CSV package rowWriter?

Tags: csv, julia

I'm using Julia. I would write a single row again and again on existed CSV file.
I think 'CSV.RowWriter' can make it happen, but I don't know how to use. Can anyone show me an example?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CSV.RowWriter` is an iterator that produces consecutive rows of a table as strings. Here is an example:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a=1:5, b=11:15)
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1     11
   2 │     2     12
   3 │     3     13
   4 │     4     14
   5 │     5     15

julia> for row in CSV.RowWriter(df)
       @show row
       end
row = "a,b\n"
row = "1,11\n"
row = "2,12\n"
row = "3,13\n"
row = "4,14\n"
row = "5,15\n"
```

You would now just need to write these strings to a file in append mode.

Most likely, since you want to append you want to drop he header. You can do it e.g. like this:

```
julia> for row in CSV.RowWriter(df, writeheader=false)
       @show row
       end
row = "1,11\n"
row = "2,12\n"
row = "3,13\n"
row = "4,14\n"
row = "5,15\n"
```

If you want me to show how to write to a file please comment.

The reason why I do not show it is that you do not need to use `CSV.RowWriter` to achieve what you want. Just do the following:

```
CSV.write(file, table, append=true)
```

---

EDIT: example of writing with `CSV.RowWriter`:

```
julia> using DataFrames, CSV

julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1, 2], b=[3, 4])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      3
   2 │     2      4

julia> isfile("test.txt") # make sure the file does not exist yet
false

julia> open("test.txt", "w") do io # create a file and write with header as the file does not exist
           foreach(row -> print(io, row), CSV.RowWriter(df))
       end

julia> readlines("test.txt") # chceck all is as expected
3-element Vector{String}:
 "a,b"
 "1,3"
 "2,4"

julia> open("test.txt", "a") do io # append to file and write without header
           foreach(row -> print(io, row), CSV.RowWriter(df, writeheader=false))
       end

julia> readlines("test.txt") # check that all is as expected
5-element Vector{String}:
 "a,b"
 "1,3"
 "2,4"
 "1,3"
 "2,4"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you show me how to write a csv file by rowWriter?

Comment: I have added an example.